# Review Queue badge list displays unrelated badge

Tags: bug, review, badges

For some reason I'm unable to upload or add the screenshot as an image for this. I get a message about an error with imgur. Here's the screenshot link:

[image]

In the review queue, you can hover over badge progress to see a list of some badges and the progress you have on them. For some reason, the Civic Duty badge (Vote 300 or more times) is shown in the list. But this isn't really a review badge, because it is not awarded *once per review queue*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, neither are Copy Editor and Electorate, the other two badges. The popup even says so:

> These badges can only be earned once.

It just shows you some other badges you can focus on while reviewing. Maybe like "Are you in doubt whether No Action is needed, or want to upvote this post? Remember that you'll get a badge if you vote enough.". The main idea being that there's always something that can be done to improve/moderate a post.